# trouble with makefile C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to set up a template folder for future projects.  I am going to incorporate google tests for my unit testing.  The issue I'm having is my makefile is not doing what I expect.  any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my project structure:

`project_root
    Makefile
    /test <-- contains google test files
    /src  <-- my cpp files`

Here is my Makefile:

```
# Google Test location
GTEST_DIR = test

# Where to find user code.
USER_DIR = src

# Flags passed to the preprocessor.
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include

# Flags passed to the C++ compiler.
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread

# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
# created to the list.
TESTS = sample1_unittest

.PHONY : all
all: $(EXE)

clean :
    rm -f $(TESTS) gtest.a gtest_main.a *.o

# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h

# Builds gtest.a and gtest_main.a.
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)

gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc

gtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# Builds a sample test.  A test should link with either gtest.a or
# gtest_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.

### these next few lines would do the job, but i'm trying to automate
### things a bit so they are commented out

#sample1.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
#   $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc
#
#sample1_unittest.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc \
#                     $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
#   $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc
#
#sample1_unittest : sample1.o sample1_unittest.o gtest_main.a
#   $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@


# here is where my trouble begins:
SRC = $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc
OBJ=$(SRC:.cc=.o)
EXE=go

%.o : %.cc $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<


$(EXE): $(OBJ) gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $< -o $@
```

could you review the section under the comment "`# here is where my trouble begins`"

When I run `$ make` i get the following error:

> make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

I've been using a similar makefile for quite a while, but now that I've addapted it for unittesting and moved the src files into their own folder it has broken.

I will be using this for all future builds so I'd really like to get this setup well now.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

**Thank you for the fix.**

I moved the the following 3 lines above .phony : all

```
SRC = $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc
OBJ=$(SRC:.cc=.o)
EXE=go
```

I also had an error at the end, the vary last line should have been:

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Beta I expect it to build an executable test sweet called "go"

Comment: cmake is easier and better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `EXE` is undefined when called in `all: $(EXE)`.
It only gets defined much lower. So your all: line is only `all:` when translated.

Comment: This fixed the issue, I'm having a secondary build issue `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:68: recipe for target 'go' failed`  I'll chase that down for a bit unless you have any suggestions

Comment: That's a linking error that has nothing to do with your makefile.